# How can add mail to this table

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Table

| server | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| srv1 | SecondName |  |
| srv2 | SecondName |  |
| srv3 | ThirdName |  |

How can I add mail to same table from Domain?
I made a request with `Get-ADUser`, but it does not work correctly.
It does not work correctly.

```
$CSVpatch = "C:\temp\address.csv"
$result = Import-Csv $CSVpatch -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default | % {
$name = $_.name;
$server = $_.server;
Get-ADUser -Properties *  -filter " (DisplayName  -eq '$name')" | Select-Object  DisplayName, mail}
$result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name server -Value $server
$result
```

Comment: What does "It does not work correctly" mean? Please be more specific. The `Name` column is supposed to have the AD Users `DisplayName` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `-Properties *` when all you need are two extra properties.

You can do this using [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) like:

```
$CSVpatch = "C:\temp\address.csv"
$result = Import-Csv -Path $CSVpatch -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default | ForEach-Object {
    $server = $_.server
    Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.name)'" -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'server'; Expression = {$server}},
                  @{Name = 'name'; Expression = {$_.DisplayName}},
                  @{Name = 'email'; Expression = {$_.EmailAddress}}
}

$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# or save as CSV perhaps?
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\address_NEW.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```